# Keepalived/Haproxy docker-compose connection refused

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, haproxy, keep-alive

**Docker Version:** Version 17.03.0-ce-mac2 (15654) 
**OS:** macOS Sierra

I am trying to setup an HA environment using docker-compose. A quick overview of the what the topology might look like is that I will have at least two instances of keepalived and haproxy running, the haproxy will be in front of multiple servers. However, in this posting I make reference to only one instance of keepalived, haproxy, and server for simplification.

The problem that I have right now is that I am unable to direct traffic to the virtual IP address that I assign to keepalived. For testing purposes in my docker compose file I have a client that tries to communicate using the VIP, and it results in a connection refused error.

```
dial tcp 192.168.99.120:80: getsockopt: connection refused
```

However, if I reach out directly to haproxy there is not a connection issue. Furthermore, I can communicate directly to the haproxy from host but not to keepalived.

I feel like this has something to do with how networks work in docker but I am pretty new to using docker and have not been able to track down the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

My configuration files are all included below.

---

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
keepalived1:
  image: neoassist/docker-keepalived:latest
  container_name: keepalived1
  volumes:
    - "./keepalived.conf:/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf"
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_IP=192.168.99.120
    - VIRTUAL_MASK=24
    - VRID=1
    - CHECK_IP=any
    - CHECK_PORT=80
    - INTERFACE=eth0
  entrypoint: sh -c 'sleep 4;/usr/bin/keepalived.sh'
  network_mode: "host"
  cap_drop:
    - NET_ADMIN
  privileged: true

haproxy1:
  image: haproxy:latest
  container_name: haproxy1
  ports:
    - 7054:7054
  volumes:
    - "./haproxy1.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg"
  environment:
    - EXPOSE=7054
  links:
    - fabric-ca-server1:fabric-ca-server1

fabric-ca-server1:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
  container_name: fabric-ca-server1
  ports:
    - 7051:7054
  environment:
    - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  volumes:
    - "./fabric-ca-server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
  command: sh -c "fabric-ca-server start -d -b admin:adminpw"

admin-client:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
  container_name: admin-client
  network_mode: "host"
  command: sh -c "sleep 14;fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u http://admin:adminpw@192.168.99.120"
```

---

haproxy.cfg

```
global
  maxconn 4096

defaults
  mode http
  maxconn 2000
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 50000
  timeout server 50000

frontend server
  bind *:7054
  mode tcp
  default_backend server_cluster

backend server_cluster
  balance source
  mode tcp
  option tcpka
  server server1 fabric-ca-server1:7054
```

---

keepalived.conf

```
vrrp_script haproxy {
 script "pidof haproxy"
 interval 2
 weight 2
}

vrrp_instance haproxy_1 {
 virtual_router_id 1
 advert_int 1
 interface eth0
 nopreempt
 state BACKUP
 virtual_ipaddress {
  192.168.99.120/24 dev eth0
 }

 track_script {
  haproxy
 }
}
```

---

ifconfig from my mac has:

```
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
inet 192.168.99.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.99.255
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will ever work with Docker for Mac because it actually uses a VM under the covers to run your Docker containers.  This *should* work on a system with native Docker support if you try using host networking rather than bridge networking.

My suggestion would be to look at either Docker swarm mode (not the standalone Docker swarm) or Kubernetes which both provide mechanisms to scale services and provide load balancing across them via a single address